# Issue with HttpClient: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest' but deprecated ResponseContentType its working

Tags: angular, typescript, header, blob, httpclient

I'm trying to update a deprecated function

```
    static generateOptions() {
        return {
            'Accept': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'responseType': ResponseContentType.Blob
        };
```

To some currently used libraries (Angular4+) like the HttpClient:

```
    static generateOptions() {
        return {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Accept': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
          }),
          responseType: 'blob',
        };
    }
```

But when changing the headers to this ones, I'm receiving an error

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'function () { _this.headers = new Map(); Object.keys(headers).forEach(function (name) { var /** @type {?} / values = headers[name]; var /* @type {?} */ key = name.toLowerCase(); if (typeof values === 'string') { values = [values]; } if (values.length > 0) { _this.headers.set(key, values); _this.maybeSetNormalizedName(name, key); } }); }' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
```

How can I handle this from my frontend?
My postcall to generate the pdf looks like this:

```
    generateDeparturePdf(item: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.config.get('apiroot') + '/reports/departure-pdf', item,         ReportsService.generateOptions())
            .map((res) => {
                return res;
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                return error._body.text();
            }); 
    }
```

I tried changing the method or returning everything in a headers but its not working. I don't want to use a deprecated function.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
    let options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      }),
      responseType:'blob' as 'json',
    }
```

since [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586) is still a open issue/feature request I don't think there is a better solution

Comment: Somehow I'm still receiving the same exception :'( should I change the whole system of the HttpClient? It says my header is not properly formatted but I don't know why does it work then with the ApplicationType property